# Google map markers in php code

Tags: php, google-maps

I have a code which should take the input of latitude and longitude from the user and display the location of the user. Well, the map is getting displayed, but the marker is not getting displayed. Please help...

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Map</title>
<script type='text/javascript'
src='https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDFLaJwxTIGpZmwfpbEyOU5XZglUq6-5iM&sensor=false'>
</script>

<?php
$lat= $_POST['lat'];
$long= $_POST['long'];
?>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var latitude = "<?php echo $lat; ?>";
    var longitude ="<?php echo $long; ?>";
function initialize()
{
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

 var mapProp = {
  zoom:8,
  center: myLatLng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),mapProp);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: myLatlng,
  map: map,
  optimized: false,
  title:'Former About.com Headquarters'
}); 
}


</script>
</head>
<body onload='initialize()'>

<div id='map_canvas' style='width:300px; height:300px;'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change:

```
position: myLatlng
```

to:

```
position: myLatLng
```

since your variable name is `myLatLng` not `myLatlng`

Comment: Whoa thanks... It worked. I didn't check that before.

Answer (score 1):

Your marker requires POST data to be constructed, but you don't have a form of any sort.